# ¿Cómo entro y salgo del modal?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Se me ha liado al insertar las funciones para cerrar y abrir el modal ya que quiero que se cierre al darle click en cualquier lugar de la pantalla y ahora por intentar hacer la función la cual no se hacer porque no me funciona no me va casi nada.

Esto es lo que tenia antes, cuando por lo menos  el modal se abría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Jquery entenderéis mejor lo que quiero hacer. Antes se me abría el modal pero no lograba de ninguna manera que se cerrara.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#botonBusqueda").click(function() {
    if ($('#modalContainer').is(':hidden')) {
      $("#modalContainer").show();
      $("#modal").css("width", "50%");
      $("#modal").css("margin-left", "20%");
    }

  });


  $("body").click(function() {
    if ($('#modalContainer').is(':visible')) {
      $("#modalContainer").hide();
    }
  });



});
```

```css
.fondo {
  background-image: url('../img/2545370.jpg');
  height: 172vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* NavBar*/

.navbar-nav {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 11%;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

form {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#modalContainer {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b909a3cc21.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>EasyLinks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--NavBar -->
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../pro/img/Icono.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      </a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Dropdown
                        </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="botonBusqueda">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
          </li>
          <div id="modalContainer">
            <div id="modal" class="input-group mb-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--NavBar -->

  <!-- Slide -->
  <section class="foo-class">
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
      <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100 align-items-center">
        <h1>All is connected!</h1>
        <h6>Llega a cualquier sitio del mundo con unos sencillos clicks!</h6>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Navega</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El modal de bootstrap se cierra al clickear fuera del mismo por defecto. Por qué no probás hacer un modal respetando la estructura de la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#examples)?. Por otro lado, veo que estás importando 2 veces `jQuery` (sin contar el primero de todos) y 2 veces el `css` de Bootstrap. Revisá lo que estás agregando.

Comment: hahaha vaya, no me había dado cuenta esos detalles, voy a revisarlo.Lo que pasa también es que yo quiero que el modal esté arriba y sin la cruz para cerrarlo ni nada y la verdad es que no logro hacerlo.

Comment: Ya pudiste resolvero o sigues necesitando ayuda?

Comment: Gracias Fernando, al final lo que hice es empezar de nuevo ya que me había liado y empecé a hacer cosas sin sentido. Mas o menos lo que echo como tu me has mostrado abajo. Ahora estoy estancado en otras cosas... jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a mostrar el ejemplo para que con un elemento cualquiera abras y con otro elemento cualquiera cierres el modal que necesitas para que lo adaptes a tu código.

Suponiendo que ya cargaste todo lo necesario de bootstrap para hacer funcionar tu DOM (consulta este [enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#template) si sigues teniendo dudas de qué debes incluir para hacerlo funcionar con Bootstrap 3)

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="abrir-modal">Abrir modal</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="mi-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Mi título genial
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Mi contenido genial y el botón que cierra este modal abierto<br>
                <button type="button" id="cerrar-modal">Cerrar modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código jquery para abrir y cerrar modal

```
(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#abrir-modal", function() {
        $("#mi-modal").modal('show');
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#cerrar-modal", function() {
        $("#mi-modal").modal('hide');
    });
})();
```